# How to fix lag in pygame when drawing multiple surfaces

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pygame-surface

What I want in my game is a circle around the player where everything is visible but outside of that circle its very hard to see stuff. Basically a flashlight aura and everything outside of that is dark and hard to see. It took me a while to get it working but now that I did the game runs at like 20FPS and is visibly laggy when normally it was running fine at 60FPS. Any ideas of how to keep the same idea but make the game run better?

```py
class Flashlight:
    def __init__(self):
        self.flashlight_surf = pygame.Surface((SCREEN_W, SCREEN_H))
        self.flashlight_surf2 = pygame.Surface((SCREEN_W, SCREEN_H))

        self.flashlight_surf2.set_colorkey((1,1,1))
        self.flashlight_surf2.set_alpha(200)
        self.flashlight_radius = 200

    def flashlight_update(self):
        self.flashlight_surf2.fill(black)

        pygame.draw.circle(self.flashlight_surf2, (1,1,1), (round(player.x) + 
        32, round(player.y) + 32), self.flashlight_radius)

        display.blit(self.flashlight_surf2, (0,0))
        self.flashlight_surf2.blit(self.flashlight_surf, (0,0))
```

Comment: What's `self.flashlight_surf` for? It seems like you're only using it to reset `self.flashlight_surf2`, which you're already doing when filling it black. What happens if you remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
self.flashlight_surf2 = pygame.Surface((SCREEN_W, SCREEN_H))
```

to

```
self.flashlight_surf2 = pygame.Surface((SCREEN_W, SCREEN_H)).convert()
```

Converting the surface can increase the blitting speed by 6 times [as stated here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/newbieguide.html)

If [convert()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert) doesn't work use [convert_alpha()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert_alpha)

Comment: @MaxTriesToCode Even if it doesn't work, make sure to always do this as it'll convert the image to the correct format for blitting. It's often always what you want.